# eclipse - export runnable jar file not working, running works

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I made a game with libGDX 1-2 years ago, I can run it from eclipse and it works.
When I want to export the jar file, I go to export - runnable jar file - 
Here I select package required libraries, and export it.

When I open the jar file nothing will happen.
[image]

Comment: Try to run your jar from console and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Nothing happens...http://i.snag.gy/bmwJa.jpg ..

Comment: That is not how you run jar. Use `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Comment: You can also try with `java -cp <jar-file-name>.jar full.package.name.ClassName` if you want to run `main` method from `ClassName` (in case your manifest doesn't provide main class).

Comment: @Pshemo I get Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed . But I have a LeapJava library imported and added to the build path. - http://i.snag.gy/8ihJ3.jpg

Comment: Actually I lied a little. You can run jar with simple `<jar-file-name>.jar` call, but in our case we want to connect input/output/error streams to our console, so we need to explicitly create JVM via console by calling `java ...`. This should allow us to see possible errors.

Comment: Didn't see your last comment. You should probably update your question with that informations. Also provide exact error message.

Comment: I fixed, the problem was that I need to set '-Djava.library.path=' when running the jar file, so I created a batch file that does that

Answer (score 0):

If your libGDX uses Gradle, all you need to do is run `gradlew dist` in the desktop folder of your project. [More Information](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-desktop)